# Hide some portion on single.php base on author

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, user-roles

I would like to hide some portion in view post base on author.

My requirement is that I have an job board theme and user can post the job. So there is "How to Apply" section in detail page.

Now, I want to auto post from other job site feed by using a author called "Aggregator". He has a role called "Aggregator".

So I want to hide "How To Apply" section, if post author role is "Aggregator".

May I know How to get and check post author role?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( !in_array('Aggregator', get_the_author_meta('roles')) ){
    //If user is not aggrigator display the info
}
```

That will get the authors roles as an array for the current post. You can pass a post id along with the 'roles' to get the data from another post.

Also note that your Aggrigator role is possibly set-up in word press in lower-case so make the if statement reflect this.